# Material UI: KeyboardTimePicker display popover wrong position

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I have component use KeyboardTimePicker, and I want to format input data with max hour: 23 and max minutes: 59, so that, I replace default input with another input to custom input. But I faced with issue:

- When I use InputProps - inputComponent, popover display wrong position
  This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";

function InlineTimePickerDemo() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      <KeyboardTimePicker
        ampm={false}
        variant="inline"
        label="With keyboard"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: () => <input value={123} />
        }}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default InlineTimePickerDemo;
```

With this code, Popover display wrong position
[Display wrong Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Nea.png)

but, when I commonent InputProps, It's work well

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      <KeyboardTimePicker
        ampm={false}
        variant="inline"
        label="With keyboard"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        //InputProps={{
        //  inputComponent: () => <input value={123} />
        //}}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

[Popover Display right positon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1DZS.png)

I tried hard to fix it, but not working, please help me :(, many thanks

[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-material-ui-p8x1s?file=/src/InlineTimePickerDemo.jsx)

Comment: Looks pretty good to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcji2.png

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't know why when I add

InputProps={{
     inputComponent: () => <input value={123} />
}}

-> Dialog Clock 's position display in center of screen (right position is below input)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1DZS.png <--- right position
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Nea.png <--- wrong position

Comment: Well, I tried several things but none of them work, at still in the wrong position :( https://codesandbox.io/s/test-material-ui-forked-4mlypm?file=/src/InlineTimePickerDemo.jsx